# Django logs in apache vhost error file, how to fix

Tags: django, apache, logging, mod-wsgi

I've a django running with WSGI and it sends logs to the error file that i setup in the vhost of apache.

the logging configuration is the following

```
 'django': {
        'handlers': ['logfile'],
        'level': 'INFO',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'django.requests': {
        'handlers': ['slack_error'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': False,
    },
    'django.requests': {
        'handlers': ['logfile'],
        'level': 'INFO',
        'propagate': True,
    },
```

and this

```
'version': 1,
 'disable_existing_loggers': True,
 'formatters': {
     'standard': {
         'format': "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
         'datefmt': "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
     },
     'onlymsg': {
         'format': '%(message)s'
     },
 },
 'handlers': {
     'logfile': {
         'level': 'INFO',
         'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
         'filename': "/var/log/web.log",
         'maxBytes': 5000000,
         'backupCount': 3,
         'formatter': 'standard',
     },
     'slack_chino_error': {
         'level': 'ERROR',
         'class': 'handler.AdminSlackHandler',
         'formatter': 'onlymsg',
         'slack_url': 'https://hooks.slack.com/...',
         'channel': '#error_notification',
         'username': SERVER_NAME
 },
```

apache vhost is the follwing

```
# LOG Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.
CustomLog /var/log/web_access.log combined
ErrorLog /var/log/web_error.log
LogLevel warn
```

Now if i open the web_error.log file it's full of django logs

```
[Mon Dec 12 12:16:20.054977 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 13255:tid 139989789542144] GET console.views.generic.generic_view
[Mon Dec 12 12:18:11.222981 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 13255:tid 139991418357504] GET console.views.user_info.UserInfo
```

and I think the reason is beacuse of the `[wsgi:error]` which I don't know why it saying so, or for other reasons that I don't know.
any help on how to remove these entires and fix everhting?

Answer (score 2):

Anything output to `stdout` or `stderr` from the Python WSGI application will be logged to the Apache error log. This is the preferred way of doing logging under Apache. It is not a good idea to use your own separate log file with the `logging` module. This is because the fact that your application can be running multi process means things like the rotating file handler from the `logging` module may not work properly.

Why do you believe it is bad that the Apache error log file is used when doing that is what is regarded as best practice when using Apache/mod_wsgi?

FWIW, typical Django logging configuration when using mod_wsgi would be:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: interesting. do you have any official source for this? or an official reference on how to manage logging

Comment: PS: i wasn't saying that is a bad thing, my question was just about the fact that error log was full of logs not meant to be errors.

Comment: The so called Apache error log is not just for errors. Apache supports many levels of messages from alert, err, warn, info and debug. Unfortunately one can't easily translate anything coming from Python to a specific log level of Apache and so everything gets logged as err level even though isn't.

Comment: I see, but in this case the log will not be rotated at all, since apache/nginx do not rotate logs (afaik)

Comment: You can have Apache do log file rotation using the ``rotatelogs`` program that comes with it and piped loggers. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/rotatelogs.html